# C# VScrollBar stop responding suddenly and keep sending the mouse down events to the parent form

Tags: c#

My Form has a Panel which has an inner panel. I have a VScrollBar inside the parent panel, which scrolls the inner panel. Everything works fine. But if I keep on clicking the up/down zip of VSCrollBar, the scrollbar seems to get crashed.

From some investigation, I got to know that, it keeps sending WM_LBUTTONDOWN message to the Form and it routed back to the Panel again, which triggers the UpdateBounds() of my outer Panel. This makes my panel spread across the form and I am not able to see any other controls on the entire form.

Has anybody come across this issue? Is there any workaround or any fix for it?

Here there are some more details about this scrollbar freezing issue.

```
    private void vsBar_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePicTops();
    }

    private void UpdatePicTops()
    {
        pnlNames.Top = (int)VB6.TwipsToPixelsY(-vsBar.Value);
        pnlValues.Top = (int)VB6.TwipsToPixelsY(-vsBar.Value);
    }
```

I have a pnlContainer which holds the pnlNames and pnlValues.

pnlContainer has vsBar (vertical scroll bar), This scrolls perfectly based on my pnlNames/pnlValues height when its exceeding.

I am setting the vsBar properties during my form load based on the child panel height.

When I keep on clicking Up and Down zip button on my vsBar suddenly makes the scroll bar behaves unexpected way. All of sudden up and down zip button disappears and then each click on my vsBar sends a WM_LBUTTONDOWN button the parent form and that again triggers UpdateBounds() without any argument to my pnlContainer , this makes my pnlContainer height and width equivalent to my form height and width.

Please feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Show us your code...VScrollBar doesn't do anything by itself.

Comment: Don't use a VScrollBar control.  Set the AutoScrollMinSize property of the parent panel to the size you want.

Comment: private void VScroll_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pnlNames.Top = -VScroll.Value;
            pnlValues.Top = -VScroll.Value;
        }

Comment: Above is the code which i have related to the scroll bar, I do not have any other event associated with this VScroll.                   @ LarsTech - Based on the layout which i want, I am not able to use autoscrollbar of my parent panel. I have to use VScrollBar only.

Comment: You will have to post more code than that for your audience to try to reproduce the problem.  Put the code in the question by editing it, not in the comments.

Comment: @LarsTech - I have added the complete code what i have around the scroll bar.

Comment: `VB6.TwipsToPixelsY` is obsolete code — I would get rid of it.  You still haven't posted anything that would reproduce the problem.  Create a new project and try to recreate the problem with the minimum of controls and code to isolate problem.  If it still occurs, post that code in your question.

Comment: @LarsTech - I agree VB6.TwipsToPixelsY() is obsolete, But i dont think that would be an issue.  This issue is re-creatable in Windows Server 2003/2008 based operating systems. Also the full PageHeap turned on those machines.